# Using CanCan within a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cancan

I am unsure if this is possible, but I want to use CanCan within my own gem.  I've tried the following code:

```
module DynamicMenu
  require 'engine' if defined?(Rails)
  require 'cancan'

    module MenuItems
      #The new dynamic_menu encapsulates 
      class DynamicMenu
    def initialize
    @actionMenuItems ||= []
    end

    def newmenuitem(name,link,method=:get,confirm="Are you sure?")
          genlink = ""

          if method==:delete
            genlink += "<a href=\"#{link}\" data-confirm=\"#{confirm}\" data-method=\"delete\" rel=\"nofollow\">
     #{name}</a>".html_safe
          elsif link==:submit
            genlink += "<a href=\"#\" data-submit=\"true\">#{name}</a>".html_safe
          elsif link == :back
            genlink = "<a href=\"#\" data-back=\"true\">#{name}</a>".html_safe
          else
           genlink = "<a href=\"#{link}\">#{name}</a>".html_safe
          end      
  @actionMenuItems << genlink.html_safe
end

    def newCanCanProtectedItem(name,link,method=:get,confirm="Are you sure?")
       actions = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(link)
    if defined?(CanCan) and can? actions[:action],actions[:controller].singularize.capitalize
        newmenuitem(name,link,method,confirm)
     else
       @actionMenuItems << "CANCAN NOT DEFINED OR ABILITY.RB PROBLEM";
     end
end

    def getItems
   return @actionMenuItems
    end

  end


  end
end
```

When doing this I get undefined method `can?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CanCan needs to rely on an ability class.  So, somehow you need to include an ability class.  The basics look something like:

```
 class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability
     def initialize(user)
     end
 end
```

I used an assumtion, but this should probably be an initializer or something, that the class was called ability.

When using CanCan in a gem you must make a new instance of the ability class, or pass it in.  I did:

```
ability = Ability.new(current_user) #You have to pass in a user
```

A user must be passed in.  It appears, however, that current_user is not defined in the scope of a gem.  So, I passed a user into my method too.

After that I was able to do:

```
ability.can? actions[:action],actions[:controller].singularize.capitalize
```